# Getting response as session expired for and API

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I have two classes `DB_Search` and `Elastic_Search` which generate the response from STAGE and PROD, but when I ran these two classes parallel using the testng.xml file, one class got a complete response but the other one got a `session-expired`-response.

These are the two classes:

```
public class DB_Search {

    @Test
    public void FinBlock() throws IOException, ParseException {

        SessionFilter session = new SessionFilter();
        RestAssured.baseURI = "login_api";
        String Response = given().auth().preemptive().basic("******", "****").filter(session).when()
                .get(RestAssured.baseURI).then().extract().response().getCookie("RAY_SESSION_ID");

        Response resp = given().cookie("RAY_SESSION_ID", Response).filter(session).when().get("API").then().extract()
                .response();

        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\***\\eclipse-workspace\\API_test\\Files\\output.json");
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
        bufferedWriter.write(resp.asString());
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

```
public class Elastic_search {

    @Test
    public void FinBlock() throws IOException, ParseException {
        SessionFilter session = new SessionFilter();
        RestAssured.baseURI = "Login_API";
        String Response = given().auth().preemptive().basic("****", "***").filter(session).when()
                .get(RestAssured.baseURI).then().extract().response().getCookie("RAY_SESSION_ID");

        Response resp = given().cookie("RAY_SESSION_ID", Response).filter(session).when().get("main_api").then()
                .extract().response();

        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\***\\eclipse-workspace\\API_test\\Files\\output1.json");
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
        bufferedWriter.write(resp.asString());
        bufferedWriter.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, which of the two classes does fail exactly?

Comment: @Z-100 sometimes it will db_search sometime elastic_search class.

Comment: So both of the classes fail, just not at the same time? Are the `RestAssured.baseURI` values different on purpose? And are the tests working independently? - If you just start one test at a time, manually; Do they both work?

Comment: @Z-100 both classes won't fail any one them will fail,RestAssured.baseURI is login API so it will be different for both classes.if i ran the classes independently i will get the response.

Comment: Have you tried debugging before? I'm interested in the value of `resp`, right after the debugger hit it. Run both tests at once, in debug mode and create a line break on the line of `Response resp = ...` -> then check the value of the response.

Comment: @Z-100 run through debuuger creating breakpoint on both class for resp line after complete exection getting one them as session expired.

Comment: That makes sense, but what were the values of the variable: `resp` in that point of time? You gotta figure out, which part of the test/app is failing. Maybe it's the FileWriter

Answer (score 0):

Both your tests set value for static variable `RestAssured.baseURI`. Hence your threads interfere.

To fix that you should either to set base path in configuration of your particular request within each your test or use full path to the endpoint in `get`.